# Change popup menu item title android

Tags: android, android-menu, oncreateoptionsmenu

I am new to android development, i m trying to change the popup menu item title. i m using onCreateOptionsMenu() , but its not changing the title. how to achieve this? code included...

MovieDetailsActivity.java

```
public class MovieDetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button magnet;
Button torrent;
private String size720p,size1080p;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.movie_details_activity);
    final Context context = this;

    final Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.MyToolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbarLayout = (CollapsingToolbarLayout)findViewById(R.id.collapse_toolbar);
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    //Extract the data…
    if (bundle != null) {
        String title = bundle.getString("movie_title");
        String screenshot = bundle.getString("screenshot");
        String yts_web = bundle.getString("yts_web");
        String rating = bundle.getString("rating");
        String imdb_url = bundle.getString("imdb_url");
        String mpa_rating = bundle.getString("mpa_rating");
        String runtime = bundle.getString("runtime");
        String genres = bundle.getString("genres");
        String synopsis = bundle.getString("synopsis");
        String poster = bundle.getString("poster");
        final String youtube = bundle.getString("youtube");

        size720p = (String) bundle.getString("size720p");
        final String magnet720p = bundle.getString("magnet720p");
        final String torrent720p = bundle.getString("torrent720p");
        size1080p = bundle.getString("size1080p");
        final String magnet1080p = bundle.getString("magnet1080p");
        final String torrent1080p = bundle.getString("torrent1080p");


        magnet = (Button) findViewById(R.id.magnet);
        magnet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Creating the instance of PopupMenu
                Context wrapper = new ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.popupMenuStyle);
                PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(wrapper, magnet);
                //Inflating the Popup using xml file
                popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup_dl_quality, popup.getMenu());
                //registering popup with OnMenuItemClickListener
                popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.hd) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent();
                            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
                            intent.setData(Uri.parse(magnet720p));
                            startActivity(intent);
                        } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.full_hd) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent();
                            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
                            intent.setData(Uri.parse(magnet1080p));
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                });

                popup.show();//showing popup menu
            }
        });//closing the setOnClickListener method

        torrent = (Button) findViewById(R.id.torrent);
        torrent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Creating the instance of PopupMenu
                Context wrapper = new ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.popupMenuStyle);
                PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(wrapper, torrent);
                //Inflating the Popup using xml file
                popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup_dl_quality, popup.getMenu());

                //registering popup with OnMenuItemClickListener
                popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.hd) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent();
                            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
                            intent.setData(Uri.parse(torrent720p));
                            startActivity(intent);
                        } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.full_hd) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent();
                            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
                            intent.setData(Uri.parse(torrent1080p));
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                });

                popup.show();//showing popup menu
            }
        });//closing the setOnClickListener method

        collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle(title);

        TextView Rating = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.imdb);
        Rating.setText(rating);
        TextView MpaaRating = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mpaRating);
        MpaaRating.setText(mpa_rating);
        TextView Runtime = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.runtime);
        Runtime.setText(runtime);
        TextView Genres = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.genres);
        Genres.setText(genres);

        ImageView Poster = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.moviePoster);
        Glide.with(Poster.getContext()).load(poster).placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder).error(R.drawable.ic_img_error).into(Poster);
        ImageView Screenshot = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ytThumb);
        Glide.with(Screenshot.getContext()).load(screenshot).into(Screenshot);
        ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.playButton);
        img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse(youtube));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {   // this does nothin
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.popup_dl_quality, menu);
    menu.findItem(R.id.hd).setTitle(size720p);
    menu.findItem(R.id.full_hd).setTitle(size1080p);
    return true;
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    onBackPressed();
    return true;
}
}
```

popup_dl_quality.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="jaswinder.yts.app.MovieDetailsActivity"
    app:theme="@style/ToolbarColoredBackArrow">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/hd"
        android:title="720p"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/full_hd"
        android:title="1080p"/>
    </menu>
```

Comment: did you try calling `activity.invalidateOptionsMenu();`?

Answer (score 1):

@JaswinderSingh Have you passed the String with key value "size720p" and "size1080p" from the previous activity??

Comment: hello thanks for the help but this doesn't solve my problem.